# Why are there no modern web browsers that allow extension access to SSL information about the site you are browsing?

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, web-browser, browser-extensions

In all my Googling, I found one version of FireFox that allowed it temporarily a long time ago, it has been discussed on the Chromium development forums for years, but yet, as of today, there is still no way for an end user to view and/or manipulate SSL information via an extension, add-on, or browser plugin.

*Why?*

Are SSL Certificates **not** an essential part of the web browsing experience? What is the justification for excluding them from browser extensions?

Aren't there many users who would like and appreciate the extra information plugins could provide while browsing SSL sites?

With SSL access, plugins could:

- Compare certificates based on different parts of the world
- Pin their own untrusted certificates for themselves
- Build their own trust networks
- Pin public SSL certs when entering regions of the world where dictatorship regimes that support censorship and spying are likely to forge big name certificates.
- Collect specific data about different certificate authorities that would be valuable to the web community at large.
- Get alerts when certain certificates match certain criteria.

**Why is it, in 2021, there are no modern web browsers that allow you to view the SSL information of the site you are currently browsing?**

Is this a case of browser makers being unwilling to fight against the entrenched system of *Trusted Certificate Authorities* which simply has more money (or political clout) backing it?

Isn't this a major hold-back technologically?

Since there are two major **open source browsers (Chromium and Firefox)**, why has the community **collectively decided** not to add this functionality?

Any other reasons you can think of?

Comment: And I'm seeing Chrome extensions that allow you to view TLS certs. Even test them against SSLLabs (which includes CAA info). Can you be more explicit about what you are hoping to see, not *why* you think you should see what want?

Comment: By the way, some of the functionality you hope could come from the extensions you envision would require that the *extension* override the basic function of the connection that the browser makes. That's at the wrong end of the tech stack (i.e. "too late") What you appear to be looking for is a custom browser where the user gets to determine at handshake time whether the connection completes. This is not a reasonable end-user function.

Comment: @schroeder I agree,  But, at least - if the extension warns the user after they connect to their bank's website that the certificate has changed unexpectedly, then they might check it out before proceeding to enter their login credentials.

Comment: Do you mean "you" the user, or an extension you install? Because you mention extensions a lot, but also say "you" instead of "an extension" where I'd expect you to. Which is weird, because it's quite easy to view both the certificate and cipher in Firefox, and indeed I don't know of any browsers clear back to like IE6 that didn't make it pretty easy to view the certificate.

Comment: @schroeder All those plugins require 3rd parties. There is no reason why you need a 3rd party to see an SSL cert loaded into your browser. And no, I don't want a "new browser" and yes it is a "reasonable end user function" as demonstrated by accepted answer.

Comment: @CBHacking Just because it's possible to view cookies in development tools doesn't mean there isn't great value to be had by making them available to extensions. The same applies to SSL certs.

Comment: @8vtwo Nor did I ever claim there wasn't. You're the one who wrote a question full of "allow **you** to", "an **end user** to", etc., all the way up to the title. I don't know about you, but personally, I'm not a browser extension! The question, as asked in the title, makes no sense; I the end user am perfectly able to view certs and ciphers, mark them as trusted or untrusted, and so on. I just asked you to clarify your question, and you went responding to claims I hadn't made.

Comment: @CBHacking Wow. Okay, You're right. I fixed the title to correct the issue. Sorry for making you feel like a browser extension :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, there are several good use cases for browser extensions to access certificate information, including the ones that you mention in your question.

For several years, it wasn't possible for browser extensions to access certificate information, but it seems that now it is possible.  There is a long thread about this on Mozilla's Bugzilla at:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1322748

See the post by Will Bamberg in the above thread (near the end).

It looks like the relevant functions are:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/getSecurityInfo

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/SecurityInfo

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/CertificateInfo

Comment: Wow that's been in firefox since 62? I thought it was removed, I must have been thinking of Google's attempt. Looks like I found my new daily browser. Thanks.

Comment: @8vtwo yeah, I've been messing around with it off-and-on over the past year or so.  You can certainly use it to do things like public key pinning and warning the user if the certificate doesn't meet certain conditions or the like.  But, as far as building your own trust network or the like, it's going to be a tall order because if the cert doesn't chain-up to a trusted root cert in the browser's cert store, you can't override the browser's security warnings.

Comment: Oh well thats too bad, but HEY its better than nothing! I think there may still be a way to turn the untusted message off? at least I manged it in Chrome with a few startup flags. I don't really see the whole point of "trusted" CAs to begin with since nobody trusts any of these unknown entities. We just care about the encryption usually. But it would be nice to build a peer to peer certificate trust system or something where there is something tangible backing the "trust"

Comment: @8vtwo You might want to take a look at Moxie Marlinspike's 'Convergence' project.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_(SSL)

Comment: While interesting, the wiki was a little light on the details. I can think of many creative ways to form webs of trust especially with some of the new modern technologies. But if you think about it, what does a CA do really? All they ask is you validate by DNS. So DNS validation of SSL certs should be considered the standard norm and requires no trust except in the ongoing validity of DNS.

Comment: @8vtwo You're right, the wikipedia article is just a summary.  See this video by Moxie for much more detail about Convergence:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Wl2FW2TcA.  He also talks about some of the other ideas that you mentioned as well in this video.  I agree with you that all of the valldation that a CA does rests on DNS.  WRT `DNS validation of SSL certs should be considered the standard norm` - this sounds like DNSSEC and/or DANE.  In that case, we would be shifting our trust from the CA's to the DNS providers and/or registrars.  Moxie talks about this in the above video as well.

Comment: You know as soon as you posted this I found a Cert-Pinner plugin (only 85 users HAH somone's hiding it well), but curiously, it does not allow you to pin all certificates. It doesn't offer any explanations.

Comment: @ mti2935 I loved the video. thank you <3

Comment: The Convergence plugin is sadly completely dead. But a much simpler version could exist. Anyone who can control 1 or more 3rd party servers or VPSs could run a secure daemon on them that will check site SSL certs from you on request, you just add the IPs of your trusted "notaries" and you can kill off CAs privately with minimal resources. Why doesn't this exist?

Comment: @8vtwo What you are describing sounds similar to 'Perspectives' (see https://www.cmu.edu/homepage/computing/2008/fall/so-walls-cant-talk.shtml), which preceded Convergence.  The problem with Perspectives is that it leaks your browsing activity to the notary.  This is what Convergence attempted to solve.  I think the reason why neither of these were adopted (and Cert-pinner has only 85 downloads, and Cert Patrol is dead, etc.) is that very few people really care.  Not many people really understand about certs, CA's, PKI, MITM attacks, etc., and most of those who do are complacent.

Comment: Simply control your own notaries and keep your request channel between them encrypted. Problem solved! Costs could be a cheap as few bucks a month. You would only need 2-3 in different geographic locations and make sure they don't connect back to you, for trusted quality of service and never worrying abut CAs on Web SSL again? Seems like a tradeoff a lot of people would make.

Comment: In fact I believe people would pay for this service. The provider could offer guarantees about anonymity the same way a VPN provider does. In fact, it would fit right into a VPN provider's product line (Of course they would have to offer detailed privacy methodology assurance)

Comment: Privacy will be a hurdle, but you are right that VPN's seem to have overcome the same hurdle.  The bigger problem is that the browser extension API will not let an extension override the browser certificate warnings.  So, if cert signature does not chain-up to a CA that the browser trusts (e.g. a self-signed cert), the user is going to see a big ugly warning.  Also, if the MITM attack is near the server (e.g. within the data center or the VPS provider's network), then this system will fail, because the notary will see the same (fake) cert that the user's browser sees.

Comment: You can disable SSL browser warnings completely. I was able to do it in Chrome with "--ignore-certificate-errors", then you just replace that screen with your own screen. Besides, the browsers are open source. If a service like that can get built I am sure we can find a way to disable all SSL warnings. The browser doesn't even need to check the certificate's validity, the extension can do it. So just turn off all SSL validation. As long as the browser still uses the cert like normal.

Comment: @8vtwo Interesting idea.  But, what makes you think you will be any more successful than Perspectives, Convergence, Cert Patrol, Cert Pinner, namecoin, etc.?  Also, there are other ways for the client to authenticate the server - e.g. PAKE/SRP.  If you want to chat offline about this: `echo -n 'bWlrZUBtZWl4bGVyLXRlY2guY29tCg==' | base64 -d`.

Comment: @8vtwo While you're at it, just use the public key as the address, and use a DHT to map the addresses to IP's, and you can eliminate DNS providers and registrars as well (at that point, it will almost be like TOR).